# Aligning single-digit and double-digit numbers in Word 2010 table of contents

Tags: microsoft-word

Problem: I have a table of contents in Word 2010. It has aligned the single-digit numbers on top of the left-hand digit of the double-digit numbers, instead of on top of the right-hand digit. Example.

```
chapter one......1  
chapter two......7  
chapter three....12
```

I would like it to align like this:

```
chapter one.......1  
chapter two.......7  
chapter three....12
```

So... is this possible in Word?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have "Ruler" visible (View menu).
Mark (select) the entire table of contents.
Now there is likely to be an "L" in the ruler, the mark for a (left aligned) tab stop where the numbers are aligned.

You need to drag away that `L` - and then add a `_|` (reverse L, right aligned tab stop) to replace it; alternatively a `_|._` (decimal) tab stop might also suit your needs.

The new symbol needs to be visible at the very left edge of the ruler, then a simple click will add it to the ruler.

Comment: Thank you Hannu. And thank you G-Man for fixing how my question displayed. You're both very kind!